# What is the domain naming process in the beta proposals?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal, beta-phase

Domain names are really, really hard to find.

I notice on [WebApps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be), there are a couple of pre-registered domains being favored, but they're all very controversial (I could've sworn I saw the top rated answer +16 at one point). I've been watching the thread on [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name-for-this-site) as well, and I believe the current top voted answer has actually dipped in and out of the negative at some point.

I understand that a domain will be chosen if some single answer reaches a unanimous consensus among the community. However, is there a time limit to that? What if the site somehow reaches a critical mass over a period of a month or two and is ready to go live, but the domain discussion is still in a tug-of-war or the gems keep getting hijacked?

It's paranoia and speculation on my part, but could this happen? What happens if the community simply cannot decide on a domain and goes back and forth for months? What happens with the SO-official pre-registered domains?

Basically, my question is this: **how will domain names be chosen and finalized for the proposals, and what is the process?** Is it simply the highest voted answer in the domain suggestion thread on the meta at the end of the site's beta phase? Or is it something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In at least one of the cases of "pre-registration" it was done after the suggestion gained quite a few up-votes on a "just in case" to prevent the likely ones being hijacked:

> This seems to be picking up some early momentum, so I registered the domain, just in case. If it doesn't get selected, no big deal. – Robert Cartaino

This happens a lot when you're deciding on a name and as it costs so little it doesn't really matter.

So I wouldn't worry about domains be registered.